# Join retornando muitos registros

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, join

Olá, já pesquisei por aqui sobre este erro e não vi nenhum que se encaixe no meu problema, então, o meu problema é que tenho duas tabelas, preciso pegar algumas informações da tabela B e inserir na consulta junto da tabela A, como por exemplo
na tabela A tenho informações de venda de item, como código, nome, valor, cupom fiscal e data de movimento, na tabela B tenho as mesmas informações porem alem de tudo isso tenho informações tributarias de cada produto, e quero um resultado de consulta com as informações da tabela A mais as informações tributarias de cada produto da tabela B.

```
select * from itemvendageral

venda_id                             loja_id maquina_id dt_contabil             st_tipovenda contador_item funcionario_id material_id pontovenda_id nu_praca    func_cancela func_transfere nu_quantidade                           vl_preco                                func_lanca  vl_precooriginal                        st_cancelado nu_motivocanc imprimiu bn_exportou dt_lanc                 func_autorizou hr_cancelamento         bn_fechamento lote_id              status dt_alt                  bn_baixaefetuada classe_id   ticket_origem                                      observacoes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      vl_servico_calculado                    vl_servico_informado                    localDeEntrega                 cancelado venda_origem api_key                                            combo_id    combo_obs                                                                                                                                              indice codigo               descricao                                                                                            local_producao item_id                              versao               dispositivo_utilizado                    hr_lanc          perfilimpressao_id classe_rodizio transferido valido desconto_id desconto_estrategia                                                                                  desconto_valor                          slot_indice arredondamento                          vl_tot
------------------------------------ ------- ---------- ----------------------- ------------ ------------- -------------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ------------ -------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ------------ ------------- -------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------- ----------------------- ------------- -------------------- ------ ----------------------- ---------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------------------ --------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ------ -------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------- ------------------------------------ -------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------- ------------------ -------------- ----------- ------ ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            1             5              1000001402  0             0           NULL         NULL           1.000                                   43.00                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 21:38:22.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 21:38:27.470 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            4.3000                                  4.3000                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  1      894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       1              5DFF0992-EDA7-444F-B7D0-E2B2FBD90BA8 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   21:38:22.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    43,00
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            2             5              1000000291  0             0           NULL         NULL           2.000                                   20.90                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 21:50:09.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 21:50:47.617 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            4.1800                                  4.1800                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  2      1000000288           WITTE 600ML GF                                                                                       2              5BCA5898-3919-4A66-8AB7-49351DC4906E 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   21:50:09.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    41,80
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            3             5              1000001252  0             0           NULL         NULL           3.000                                   20.90                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 21:50:27.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 21:50:47.640 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            6.2700                                  6.2700                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  3      834                  SESSION GF 600ML                                                                                     2              62859FB4-DD2D-40B8-BAEF-893C588C605E 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   21:50:27.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    62,70
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            4             5              1000000077  0             0           NULL         NULL           1.000                                   17.90                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 21:50:44.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 21:50:47.653 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.7900                                  1.7900                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  4      1000000075           X WALS GF                                                                                            2              2CCA95C6-6C19-4F93-B235-FE66FFB794FC 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   21:50:44.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    17,90
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            5             5              1000001078  0             0           NULL         NULL           1.000                                   10.40                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 22:00:39.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 22:00:41.403 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1.0400                                  1.0400                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  5      6654                 WALS VERANO 600ML                                                                                    0              9B49FAEF-7F5F-405E-BC0B-457049F2E7F8 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   22:00:39.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    10,40
9A46FAE5-AC6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 4       5          2017-07-20 00:00:00.000 3            6             5              1000001269  0             0           NULL         NULL           1.000                                   20.90                                   5           0.00                                    N            NULL          1        NULL        2017-07-20 22:11:56.000 0              NULL                    NULL          -1                   -1     2017-07-20 22:12:02.630 0                NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2.0900                                  2.0900                                  NULL                           0         0                                                               0                                                                                                                                                                  6      849                  VERANO GF 600ML                                                                                      2              EF868F6C-AB86-4923-98FC-C92932467873 8.5.1.472            CAIXA1                                   22:11:56.0000000 0                  0              0           1      0                                                                                                                0.00                                    0           0.00                                    20,90
```

125 mil linhas

```
select * from fiscal.comprovantedetalhe

comprovante_id                       ordem       codigo               descricao                      qtd                                     unidade valor                 aliquota cancelado dt_alt                  vl_unitario           ecf_serie            ecf_id      ecf_coo     ecf_ccf     ecf_datahora            base_icms             cod_ncm              prod_origem cfop       cst_icms aliq_icms_iss          cst_pis aliq_pis               cst_cofins aliq_cofins            reducao_bc_icms        dt_mov     cest    codigo_servico  item_lista_servico tipo_aliquota
------------------------------------ ----------- -------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------------------------- ------- --------------------- -------- --------- ----------------------- --------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- --------------------- -------------------- ----------- ---------- -------- ---------------------- ------- ---------------------- ---------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------- ------- --------------- ------------------ -------------
A7C2E9C1-AD6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 1           10000000001025       BERLINER 300ML                 2.0000                                  UN      27,80                 T2500    0         2017-07-20 21:44:31.817 13,90                 BE091710100011203048 1           5430        2918        2017-07-20 21:44:29.000 30,58                 22030000             0           5102       00       25                     02      1,69                   02         7,69                   0                      2017-07-20 0000000                                    ICMS
A7C2E9C1-AD6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 2           810                  FILET C FRITAS                 1.0000                                  UN      61,00                 T0840    0         2017-07-20 21:44:31.840 61,00                 BE091710100011203048 1           5430        2918        2017-07-20 21:44:29.000 67,10                 21069090             0           5101       00       8,4                    01      1,65                   01         7,6                    0                      2017-07-20 0000000                                    ICMS
81F1ADE1-AD6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 1           822                  PALMITO PUPUNHA                1.0000                                  UN      25,00                 T0840    0         2017-07-20 21:45:25.110 25,00                 BE091710100011203048 1           5431        2919        2017-07-20 21:45:22.000 27,50                 21069090             0           5101       00       8,4                    01      1,65                   01         7,6                    0                      2017-07-20 0000000                                    ICMS
81F1ADE1-AD6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 2           586                  WITTE 300ML                    1.0000                                  UN      10,90                 T2500    0         2017-07-20 21:45:25.110 10,90                 BE091710100011203048 1           5431        2919        2017-07-20 21:45:22.000 11,99                 22030000             0           5102       00       25                     02      1,69                   02         7,69                   0                      2017-07-20 0000000                                    ICMS
81F1ADE1-AD6D-E711-8062-1C1B0DF049F3 3           906                  DULCE LAMB                     1.0000                                  UN      25,00                 F1       0         2017-07-20 21:45:25.110 25,00                 BE091710100011203048 1           5431        2919        2017-07-20 21:45:23.000 27,50                 22072020             0           5405       60       0                      01      1,65                   01         7,6                    0                      2017-07-20                                            ICMS
```

75 mil linhas

```
    select a.codigo,a.descricao,a.vl_preco,b.base_icms,b.aliq_icms_iss 
            from itemvendageral a
            left join fiscal.comprovantedetalhe as b on a.codigo=b.codigo


codigo               descricao                                                                                            vl_preco                                base_icms             aliq_icms_iss
-------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------- ----------------------
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   43,00                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   43,00                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   43,00                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
894                  FISH AND CHIPS                                                                                       43.00                                   47,30                 8,4
```

Com 15 segundos de comando ja tinha 780 Mil linhas, ele vai gerando meio q infinito ja deixei por mais de 2 minutos, e nao acaba rsrsrs

Mas o problema vem ai, quando eu faço um select na tabela A ela me retorna 125 mil registros, quando faço um select na tabela B ela me retorna 75 Mil registros, quando faço com o "join"(independente de qual seja) me retorna mais de 1M de registros.

Comment: coloca como é sua tabela e o que tem que filtrar

Comment: `JOIN` é um produto cartesiano, então ele sempre irá multiplicar as linhas. Se você informar dados de exemplo das tabelas podemos te ajudar.

Comment: editei o post para um melhor intendimento.

Comment: Quais são as `PRIMARY KEYS` das suas tabelas?

Comment: itemvendageral : venda_id(PK,FK,UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, NAO NULO)
        contador_item(PK,SMALLINT,NAO NULO)
        
fiscal.comprovantedetalhe : comprovante_id(PK,uniqueidentifier, nao nulo)
          ordem(PK,int,nao nulo)

Comment: O `contador_item` é igual a `ordem`?

Comment: sim. 
obs: estou aprendendo a usar este site rsrs

Comment: Então faz assim, no `JOIN` adiciona `AND a.contador_item=b.ordem` e me fala se deu certo. Se der escrevo a resposta explicando

Comment: com o contador e ordem ele manteve o resultado infinito, porem com and a.venda_id=b.comprovante_id funcionou, porem as informações que chegam da tabela fiscal.comprovantedetalhe vieram NULL

Comment: Essas tabelas possuem chaves estrangeiras ligando uma a outra?

Comment: @AlexAgnar, você possui todas as informações necessáras para a sua consulta na tabela comprovantedetalhe. Pelo que eu conheço de sistemas de vendas, esta tabela possui o código do item, a descrição do produto no momento da venda e as informações de ICSM.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `JOIN` é o resultado da junção das linhas da tabela A com a tabela B. A cláusula `ON` restringe resultados dessa junção. Então você deve construir o `ON` do `JOIN` com base nas colunas da chave estrangeira das tabelas. Para determinar quais colunas são utilizadas na chaves, execute a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT pai.name AS pai,
       c_pai.name AS coluna_pai,
       filho.name AS filho,
       c_filho.name AS coluna_filho
  FROM sys.tables pai
       INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk ON fk.parent_object_id = pai.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c_pai ON c_pai.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
                                   AND c_pai.column_id = fk.parent_column_id
       INNER JOIN sys.tables filho ON filho.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c_filho ON c_filho.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
                                     AND c_filho.column_id = fk.referenced_column_id
 WHERE (pai.name = 'itemvendageral'
   AND filho.name = 'comprovantedetalhe')
    OR (pai.name = 'comprovantedetalhe'
   AND filho.name = 'itemvendageral')
```

Reescreva seu `JOIN` utilizando as colunas de resultado da `query` anterior como no modelo abaixo:

```
...
LEFT JOIN tabela_filha b ON b.coluna_filha_1 = a.coluna_pai_1
                        AND b.coluna_filha_2 = b.coluna_pai_2
                        -- ... Quantas colunas houverem
                        AND b.coluna_filha_z = b.coluna_pai_z
...
```

---

> [**Usando junções externas**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> As junções externas retornam linhas apenas quando há pelo menos uma linha nas tabelas que corresponde à condição da junção. As junções internas eliminam as linhas que não correspondem a uma linha da outra tabela. Entretanto, as junções externas retornam todas as linhas de pelo menos uma das tabelas ou exibições mencionadas na cláusula `FROM`, contanto que essas linhas atendam algum critério de pesquisa `WHERE` ou `HAVING`. Todas as linhas são recuperadas da tabela esquerda referenciada com uma junção externa esquerda, e todas as linhas da tabela direita referenciada na junção externa direita. São retornadas todas as linhas de ambas as tabelas em uma junção externa completa.
>
> O `SQL Server` usa as seguintes palavras-chave `ISO` para as junções externas especificadas em uma cláusula `FROM`:
>
> - `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ou `LEFT JOIN`;
> - `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN`;
> - `FULL OUTER JOIN` ou `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: Executei o comando por completo e nao me retornou nenhum resultado, porem procurando a relaçao apenas do pai ele me retorna 6 linhas, nao tendo relação com a tabela comprovantedetalhe.

Comment: Nao acredito que tenha vinculo, pois quando uma venda é feita no sistema, ele alimenta a tabela itemvendageral, quando é feito com impressora fiscal ele alimenta a itemvendageral e a fiscal.comprovantedetalhegeral, não há ligações entre elas.
Mas na questão de obter a informação eu consegui resolver agora, percebi a existência de uma outra tabela, fiscal.material o qual possui as informações de cada material, mas sem vinculo de venda, desta forma consigo fazer o join outros problemas.
Obrigado pela ajuda @Sorack

Comment: Sobre “O problema é que o JOIN é um produto cartesiano”, quem conhece SQL sabe que JOIN não é produto cartesiano. Para obter produto cartesiano utiliza-se CROSS JOIN (segundo sintaxe SQL-92) //  A utilização de JOIN sem definição do tipo de junção é a mesma coisa que INNER JOIN.

Comment: Sobre “JOIN é o resultado da multiplicação das linhas da tabela A com a tabela B”, quem conhece Teoria dos Conjuntos sabe que multiplicar A por B é a mesma coisa que obter o produto cartesiano. E, como explicado anteriormente, quem conhece SQL sabe que JOIN _não_ é produto cartesiano.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu conheço de sistemas de vendas, a tabela comprovantedetalhe possui todas as inforações necessárias para sua consulta:

- codigo - Código do produto
- descricao - Descrição do produto no momento da venda
- valor - valor é unitário (preço)  no momento da venda
- base_icms
- aliq_icms_iss

Se você precisa da última descrição do produto e preço atual, você deve verificar na tabela de produto ou alguma outra tabela. Também acho que você precisa agragar os e nâo retornar a lista de todos.

Sobre o seu join estar fazendo um produto "cartesiano", isto ocorre por que você está tentando ligar as tabelas por campos errados. O campo código não faz parte da chave primária entre as tabelas, bem como não prove a unicidade dos registros sozinho em uma das tabelas.

Verifique as ligações das tabelas usando sp_help e você verificará que não há nenhuma constrant de ligação no campo código. Este campo está provalmente ligando com a tabela de produtos. Se houver uma ligação entre essas tabelas, a ligação será por uma chave composta que você deve usar em seu join.